# Android: ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -130 building release

Tags: android, gradle, build, release

So, just updated to Android Studio 1.4 Beta 4 and having trouble building a release build. I can build a debug build fine. This is the error I get:

```
ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -130
```

Upon further inspection, I see this:

```
String index out of range: -130
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -130
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:223)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:400)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:221)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Any ideas? I've tried with Gradle 2.3 - 2.7 and always get this error building a release build.

build.gradle from main module:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern

buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// This does not break the build when Android Studio is missing the JRebel for     Android plugin.
apply plugin: 'com.zeroturnaround.jrebel.android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'XXX'
        keyPassword 'XXX'
        storeFile file('../signing/keystore.jks')
        storePassword 'XXX'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.coffeemeetsbagel"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 605
    versionName '2.0.6.0'
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    multiDexEnabled true
}

productFlavors {
    lollipop {
        minSdkVersion 21
    }

    everything {
        minSdkVersion 16
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        debuggable false
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
    superuser.initWith(release)
    superuser {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/license'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile files('libs/commons-validator-1.4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/com.kontagent.android.sdk.jar')
compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-4.0.4.jar')
compile files('libs/apsalar.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.3'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:1.8.8'
compile 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.adobe.creativesdk:image:4.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile project(':core')
compile project(':layouts')
compile project(':volley')
}
```

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file (stripping out any keys etc.)

Comment: Updated w/ build.gradle from main module

Comment: Can you try running the gradle build from the command line just to see if it's an issue with AS?

Answer (score 51):

If you're using Android Studio, selecting the Gradle Console will show you where the problem lies. In my case, it was duplicate textView identifiers that caused this error.

Comment: This is the solution! Check the Gradle Console.

Comment: what is textView identifiers

Comment: All of your UI elements should have an id, e.g. <TextView android:id="@+id/text"/>

Comment: this is perfect solution

Comment: To access Gradle console View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle Console

Answer (score 29):

Worked By adding this in build.gradle

```
 lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

Comment: This will remove the lint checks but will not resolve the root cause of the issues.  It's probably best to resolve the errors by looking at the gradle console.  At least take a look at the errors and judge if they are worth fixing :)

Comment: it works but can you please explain a bit. what was the problem and why it works

Comment: yeah it will work.. this code simply removing the lint checks in release build. better you have to resolve the errors before generating the apk. some times it seems difficult thats why i added this two lines in build.gradle... :)

Answer (score 6):

My error is

> ExternalSystemException: String index out of range:-

My app support Turkish and English language. My English strings.xml contains

```
 <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
```

and my Turkish strings.xml do not contains

```
<string name="hello_world">Bla bla!</string>
```

When i add `<string name="hello_world">Bla bla!</string>` to Turkish strings.xml file the problem solved.

Note: Please look Android Studio's Gradle Console
[image]

Comment: Please look Android Studio's Gradle Console did show the compile errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with Android Studio 1.4 Build on September 28, 2015 
What I did was :

1. Started a build on the main gradle script - that created a run configuration in the menu.
2. Edited the run configuration by adding ":app:assembleRelease"  on the script parameters row. and started it.
3. The gradle build showed me that I had missing translations in the main strings.xml file.

After fixing this. Generate Signed APK finished without problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but with this error:

```
ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -119
```

My problem was that in the string editor i forgot to set a default variable into my translation, after adding it, the problem was solved.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

So I reverted back to Android Studio 1.3 and the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old thread, however the following info might be useful for some people. I was getting a bit different message (but similar, googling for the following message redirects me to this thread.)

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> String index out of range: 0
```

For me the problem was the string.xml was missing the name for a string resource as mentioned below.

```
<string name="">Some strings...</string>
```

Adding the proper resource name resolved the issue.

```
<string name="some_string">Some strings...</string>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have same problem. my Android Studio version is ver2.1.1

My strings.xml contains

```
<string name="title_connecting">connecting...</string>
```

then I change to the following statement. the problem solved.

```
<string name="title_connecting">connecting..</string>
```

Comment: Do you know, the key lay to this question?