# Android Studio: ExternalSystemException

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

When I am opening a project (Android Application) in my Android Studio, it shows externalSystemException. (I cloned this android application into my system from a github repo).

> Event Log: *ExternalSystemException:* **Unable to save**
>   '/home/prasang/Privly/privly-android/local.properties'/home/rest path
>   of app/-android/local.properties (Permission denied)

Comment: do you update android-studio recently ?

Comment: No. I've not updated my android studio. Current version: 1.5

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33196744/2826147

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using a mac or a windows machine but this fix will work for Mac.

I encountered the same error after cloning a copy of the android transition tutorial from github here on Mac OS Sierra:

```
https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations
```

To correct the error, you have to go into your mac and find the folder where you had clone the code. Then you will need to "Get Info".

[image]

Now, change the permission at the bottom so that the system, staff and everyone can "Read and Write" to the folder. Then try opening the repo in android studio again and you will find that the error has disappeared.

[image]