# Error opening Android React-Native project on AndroidStudio through MacOS

Tags: macos, android-studio, react-native

I'm trying to open an existing `Android React-Native` project through `AndroidStudio`, however the following exceptions are displayed to me:

```
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Unable to save ...local.properties (Permission denied)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: ...local.properties (Permission denied)
```

My operating system is the MacOs and Android project was created by the command:

```
react-native init exercises
```

How can I solve ?

Comment: Looks like you don't have a permission to create new file in that particular folder. Are you the Admin of this os ?

Comment: Yes, I am the system administrator.

Comment: Start your android emulator manually and run 'adb devices' in command line terminal, what is the output ?

Comment: When executing this command, the following appeared to me in the terminal: emulator -5554 device

Comment: Any suggestion ?

Comment: There are several answers for question similar to yours, here's one and hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35691435/2949966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the `react-native init exercises` command was not creating the project correctly.

I needed to change the read and write permissions on the project folder in order to work correctly.

I followed this link:

[Android Studio: ExternalSystemException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691435/android-studio-externalsystemexception)