# Generate Assigned APK String index out of range

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I trying to generate assigned apk from Android Studio, but get this error:

Also I'm using Ionic.

```
String index out of range: -75
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -75
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:416)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575778/android-externalsystemexception-string-index-out-of-range-130-building-relea

Comment: I saw it.. but it's not working none of...

Comment: at least, specify what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of your translation strings. 
check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38626710/271669

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use api strings like google maps api and it is duplicated in some way like the same value but different string names or appears in more than one strings.xml ie(language strings) the this error will occur what is needed to be done just use the api key string in a default language string and mark it as not translatable

```
<string name="map_api_key" translatable="false">AIzaSyCZc********U9KVUf**2f</string>
```

and any other api related strings