# getting error while build signed apk ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -97

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, signed

i m build signed apk and i have android studio 2.1.2

my build.gradle file as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.my.pkg"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22+'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.+'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


  compile project(':cropper')
```

}

When i build apk i get following error
**ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -97**

```
  String index out of range: -97
  com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -97
at      org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
at    com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:416)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:222)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

any idea how can i solve this ? you all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: Kalvadiya did u tried cleaning the code and then building?

Comment: Jagjit Singh- Yes i clean project but still getting same error

Comment: I'll go ahead and mention that all `compile files('libs/` lines are unnecessary... `compile fileTree... ` already compiles your JAR files. Doesn't fix the problem, but just a pointer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: ExternalSystemException: String index out of range: -130 building release](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575778/android-externalsystemexception-string-index-out-of-range-130-building-relea)

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by missing translation strings

to see the error run

```
./gradlew assemble
```

from your project root.
you will see something like this

[image: String out of bound exception gradle]

If your string is not translatable like fb app id, then just set translatable attribute to false

[image]

In other case, make sure you have translations in all languages you specified

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575778/android-externalsystemexception-string-index-out-of-range-130-building-relea#answer-33413713) basically look at gradle console it will show you where the problem.

Comment: Its Better to flag as duplicate rather than adding new answer.

Comment: @Spartan Noted, and flagged.