# Gradle Error: String index out of range: 0

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to compile an Android project with Gradle and getting a weird error. 
When I run `./gradlew tasks --stacktrace`. Tried clean rebuild, fresh clone of repo, different branches, colleagues are able to build aok.

Looking for ideas of things to check/try to fix this.

***update: reverting to Gradle 2.11 and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6` seems to have fixed the issue. ***

Here's the stack:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
String index out of range: 0

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaReflectionUtil.toMethodName(JavaReflectionUtil.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaReflectionUtil.writeablePropertyIfExists(JavaReflectionUtil.java:156)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader$CachingPropertyApplicator.configureProperty(ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader.addPropertiesToProject(ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader.java:76)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader.setProjectProperties(ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader.load(ProjectPropertySettingBuildLoader.java:49)
        at org.gradle.initialization.NotifyingSettingsLoader.findAndLoadSettings(NotifyingSettingsLoader.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:118)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
```

### System details:

### Gradle 2.14.1

Build time:   2016-07-18 06:38:37 UTC
Revision:     d9e2113d9fb05a5caabba61798bdb8dfdca83719

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_101 (Oracle Corporation 25.101-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64

Comment: do you have a method `get()`, `is()` or `set(...)` in your app that gradle wants to access via reflection by removing the beans-prefix "get" / "set" / "is"?

Comment: try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36717739/1517029

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`=` is a key-value separator. If you want to split sections in properties file you can use a comment:

```
foo.bar=foo
#=======
foo.baz=baz
```

More info can be found in: [properties file format](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23095_01/Platform.93/ATGProgGuide/html/s0204propertiesfileformat01.html).

Answer (score 40):

A merge conflict caused this for me. And the conflict was in `gradle.properties`. The lines like `<<<<<<< HEAD` are the reason I think. It would have been helpful if the message was more descriptive.

Comment: thank you for this answer. There is a reason you have 11 upvotes by now.

Comment: Thank you for saving hours of time solving this!

Comment: Thank you for saving hours of time solving this! [2]

Answer (score 6):

I found the issue by deleting all the entries in my global gradle.properties file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

So figured there must be something in my previous file that gradle didn't like. After copy and pasting several sections I found this to be the culprit

`=======`

I'd been using `======` to split the sections of my gradle properties (I have open source and commercial keys/properties defined).

In previous version of gradle 2.11 this was aok and compiled fine but on 2.14.1 you get the cryptic error "String index out of range: 0".

Answer (score 2):

For me, issue came due to SVN conflict for gradle.properties as below:
bin             build.gradle            gradle.properties       gradle.properties.r91662    src
build               build.num           gradle.properties.mine      gradle.properties.r91979    tmp

Once, I made gradle.properties as svn resolved, gradle build started working fine.

Comment: Thank you for this. When I read your comment I went and checked mine and it was the same thing.

Comment: Gradle 4.9 here, and trying to resolve merge conflicts, as well.  A better error message such as, "Malformed gradle.properties file," would have saved 15 minutes of my life.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates there is some wrong values in gradle.properties, please remove invalid enteries.

Answer (score 0):

delete the   `~/.gradle/`  dir  worked for me,Gradle `Exception:String index out of range:0`  when I update my android studio to `2.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Check your `settings.gradle`, if it contains any **removed/non-existing** module in your project.

I had an **already removed** module still **lying** in the `settings.gradle` file. Removing it solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

check your files it might be you have an unresolved merge conflicts which added extra character to your code which is not needed like <===== head or other git syntax with the help of github vscode extension will help to reduce the search and poing you to the foreign unwanted character immediately

delete the ~/.gradle/ dir