# Why my design tab is blank in android studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio

Why I have this problem? I closed activity_main.xml tab and reopen, I restart android studio.

[How can I sort this problem?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRp5H.png)

Comment: In the top right corner, there is a red icon click maybe it will help you.

Comment: @SajadHosseini Open this link [link] (https://imgur.com/gallery/mo3dXXi)

Comment: Do you use to contribute to this project and use git?

Comment: No. this is what i will do, reinstall

Comment: Before doing that check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737668/gradle-error-string-index-out-of-range-0)